# How do I avoid double clicks with external onClick and internal Link?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a problem with nextjs 13.. let me explain:

I have a card, this card has an external div and an internal link to go to the single product page.
On the external div I set an onClick to make the card go into focus (I need onClick because I manage the scrolling of the carousel with the keyboard and click of the mouse). My problem is that if I click on the card and then it gets focus, as soon as I click on the link to go to the single product page the focus disappears and nothing happens. I have to click the link again. Can you tell me how I could avoid this?

this is the code:

```
<div
      className={`relative h-[350px] rounded-2xl  (w-[480px])  ${
        index == selection
          ? 'border-t-2 border-width-[30px] border-solid border-primary-400'
          : ''
      }`}
      onClick={()=>setSelection(index)}
    >
      <Image......
       ..........
       .........

      <Link href={`/shop/${data.id}`}>
      
          Watch now
    
      </Link>
    </div>
```

I would like the first click on the link to go directly to the course page

Comment: check whether the buttonCustom is wrap in a tag or not in dev tool.
if not then do pass passHref prop to link

Comment: The onClick must be on the outside so it can change the edge of the card.

Comment: The button is for style only

Comment: Edit the code as it may cause confusion

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this issue is to prevent the onClick event on the link from bubbling up to the parent div when it is clicked. This can be achieved by adding an event parameter to the onClick function of the link, and calling the stopPropagation() method on the event object. Here is an example of how you can modify your code to achieve this:

```
 <div
  className={`relative h-[350px] rounded-2xl  (w-[480px])  ${
    index == selection
      ? 'border-t-2 border-width-[30px] border-solid border-primary-400'
      : ''
  }`}
  onClick={() => setSelection(index)}
>
  <Image...
  <Link href={`/shop/${data.id}`} onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}>
    Watch now
  </Link>
</div>
```

By calling stopPropagation() on the event object, you are preventing the onClick event from bubbling up to the parent div when the link is clicked, thus ensuring that the div remains in focus and the link is followed directly on the first click.